# Showing 404 in spring mvc

Tags: java, spring-mvc

HTTP Status 404 - /SpringMVCHibernate/WEB-INF/views/user/userHome.jsp
shown in the webpage as error, even the page userHome.jsp is present in the correct package.

Thanking in Advance

Comment: If possible please add code too.

Comment: Post your entire code !

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the path given in @RequestMapping annotation on a controller method.Check for the controller method which returns userHome.jsp view.

Refer spring controller documentation
https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/3.2.x/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-controller

Comment: first of all thanks for the reply...... I checked but the controller and it was annotated correctly

Comment: Post your entire code. Also check if component scan is enabled in spring context xml

Answer (score 0):

The error message says for 404 that it's looking for userHome.jsp. And indeed, your controller returns the following view name: " userHome". But in your case  shows that your file is naled  userHome.jsp. The case matters.

Try returning the properly cased view name which matches the JSP userHome.jsp from the controller. Currently the controller returns Hello while the JSP is named userHome.jsp, causing the 404

@Controller
public class UserHomeController {

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/greeting")
public String sayHello (Model model) {
    model.addAttribute("greeting", "Hello");
    //return "Hello"; 
    return "userhome"; 
}
```

}